# d3.js pan and zoom jumps when using mouse after programatic zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to center my d3 graph when it loads. So I run

```
var g = svg.append("g");

//... then later

g.call(zoom.transform, center);
```

It's not actually centering, it's just scaling right now. But the scale works. The problem is, when I then scroll to zoom in or out, it starts from `1` instead of `0.5`. So it jumps.

Here's my [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/luqihagaqa/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are applying your event on a different object (the `g`) then what the zoom is set up on (the `svg`).  Since the zoom event is referenced against the element it is applied to, `d3` does not now about your initial centering.  From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom-transforms):

> The zoom behavior stores the zoom state on the element to which the
>   zoom behavior was applied, not on the zoom behavior itself. This is
>   because the zoom behavior can be applied to many elements
>   simultaneously, and each element can be zoomed independently. The zoom
>   state can change either on user interaction or programmatically via
>   zoom.transform.

Changing your call to `svg.call(zoom.transform, center);` fixes your issue.

Complete code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    transform = d3.zoomIdentity;

var points = d3.range(2000).map(phyllotaxis(10));

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var g = svg.append("g");

g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(points)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("drag", dragged));

svg.call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

function center() {
  return d3.zoomIdentity
        .scale(0.5);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function phyllotaxis(radius) {
  var theta = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));
  return function(i) {
    var r = radius * Math.sqrt(i), a = theta * i;
    return {
      x: width / 2 + r * Math.cos(a),
      y: height / 2 + r * Math.sin(a)
    };
  };
}

svg.call(zoom.transform, center);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. When converting from d3.v3 to d3.v5, I didnt realize I had let zoom = d3.zoom().on('zoom', function(){ inner.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)}); inner.call(zoom) and then later on svg.call(zoom.transform, transform); ... I changed that inner.call(zoom) to svg.call(zoom) and now works. Thanks!