# d3.js V4 zoom jumps after a calculated zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to have the ability to pan and zoom SVG objects after I have centered and zoomed to them on page load programatically. (The actual use case is a floor plan that zooms to offices.)

For my simple example, I have 2 rectangles that load with an initial transition. (This simplifies greatly my actual use case.)

After the automatic transition, when the user tries to pan or zoom - the rectangles jump back to their intitial position.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597582/d3-js-pan-and-zoom-jumps-when-using-mouse-after-programatic-zoom?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) stack overflow question is close, but the solution does not work for me. Calling d3.select on the parent SVG (#rectSVG) seems close, BUT the top margin and left margin are now incorrect.

The javascript file:

```
var rectData = [
   { "x_axis": 10, "y_axis": 10, "color" : "green" },
   { "x_axis": 500, "y_axis": 10,  "color" : "purple"}
   ];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 1800)
                                    .attr("height", 1200)
                                    .attr("id","rectSVG")
                                    .append("g")
                                    .attr("id","groupRect");

var rectangle = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
                            .data(rectData)
                            .enter()
                            .append("rect")
                            .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                            .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                            .attr("fill",function (d) { return d.color; })
                            .attr("width", 200)
                            .attr("height", 100);

var centerScale = 1;
translate = [500, 500];

  d3.select("#groupRect").transition()
        .attr("transform", "translate("+translate+")scale(" + centerScale + ")")
        .duration(650);

var svgZoomMM =  d3.select("#rectSVG");

var _zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 1000]) 
      .on("zoom", function() {  
    d3.select("#groupRect")    
    .attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  });

  svgZoomMM.call(_zoom);
```

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it jumps is because you have manually transformed by selecting the rectSVG and translating it. The zoom transform event (d3.event.transform) doesn't know that the react has been translated (you can verify by checking d3.event.transform.x and d3.event.transform.y). In order it tell the zoom transform event that the graph has been transformed, you need to create a new transform event like 
`var t = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(500, 500).scale(1);` and apply it to the zoomable SVG `svgZoomMM.transition().duration(650).call(_zoom.transform, t);`

Working example
https://jsfiddle.net/qj2r70wa/