# d3 zoom - how to set initial transform

Tags: d3.js

I have a basic tree set up as shown here: https://codepen.io/MichelWeber/pen/GRJxbZJ using d3 v5.
What I'm trying to do is set the initial translate/transform for the zoom so that when panning the tree it doesn't jump.  At first I want to center the top/parent tree node, but d3 zoom will start at 0,0 which causes the jump.  I have not been able to find how to set it to something other than 0,0

```
var zoomListener = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3.0]).on("zoom", zoom);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .call(zoomListener)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+ width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");

function zoom() {
  var event = d3.event
  var transform = d3.event.transform
  scale = d3.event.transform.k
  $("#status").text("x: " + transform.x.toFixed(2) + " y: " + transform.y.toFixed(2) + " scale: " + scale.toFixed(2));
  var trans = "translate(" + transform.x + "," + transform.y + "), scale(" + scale + ")";
  svg.attr("transform", trans)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [d3.js pan and zoom jumps when using mouse after programatic zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597582/d3-js-pan-and-zoom-jumps-when-using-mouse-after-programatic-zoom)

Comment: Completely possible.  I don't have the 'g' separate from svg, so I need to change the code a bit and check if that is the case.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.  I needed to apply the zoom call to the correct selection.  Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the selections needed to be split apart:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var g = svg.attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    //.call(zoomListener)//.transform, d3.zoomIdentity)
    .append("g");
svg.call(zoomListener);
svg.call(zoomListener.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(-100, 50));

function zoom() {
  var transform = d3.event.transform
  scale = d3.event.transform.k
  $("#status").text("x: " + transform.x.toFixed(2) + " y: " + transform.y.toFixed(2) + " scale: " + scale.toFixed(2));
  var trans = "translate(" + transform.x + "," + transform.y + "), scale(" + scale + ")";
  g.attr("transform", trans)
}
```